# Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to execute an SQL query in rails view file. Here is the query

```
scount=SubUrl.where("main_url_id=? and pc > ? and sub_id = ? and b_id > ? and dd = ?", result.id,0,@subids,0,1) %>
```

But I'm getting the following error.

Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `suburls`.* FROM `suburls`  WHERE (main_url_id=16 and product_count > 0 and sub_id = 53,112,110,111 and b_id > 0 and dd = 1)

I think its because sub_id has many id's. How to assign sub_id one at a time and get the required scount

Answer (score 2):

Could you use `IN` instead of `=`?

```
scount=SubUrl.where("main_url_id = ? AND pc > ? AND sub_id IN (?) "\
                    "AND b_id > ? AND dd = ?", result.id,0,@subids,0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@scount = []

@subids.each do |subid|
@scount << SubUrl.where("main_url_id=? and pc > ? and sub_id = ? and b_id > ? and dd = ?", result.id,0,subid,0,1)
end
```

Comment: I tried with what you told. But it is returning scount as 0. when I checked the subids content it has all the results I want. But for some reason it is returning zero.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error once. It was caused by a date comparison using ">" with a variable that was an array of dates instead of a single date. My advice to others with this issue is to look closely at your query and make sure that the values you are passing into it are what they should be.

Edit: while my answer does not answer the op's specific problem, googling the mysql error led me to this question. The basic concept here is that a mysql operand is being used incorrectly. In the op's case, the 'in' operand needed to be used in conjunction with wrapping his list of values in parentheses. (They were misusing the "=" operator)